# adding menu items to the right click app menu in the dock casues them to be re-added each time i click

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

so i've been trying to add items to the right click menu
when u right click on the app icon in the dock in macos

but when i do it with this code whenver i right click the app icon
it re-adds the menu item

```
 class myclass: NSObject , NSApplicationDelegate{


   func applicationDockMenu(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu? {


    dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "test1", action: nil, keyEquivalent:     "")

    return dockMenu
   }
```

[image]

Comment: where is your `dockMenu` defined?

Comment: @AmirKhan outside of myclass  as  "let dockMenu = NSMenu()"

Comment: Follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817214/when-to-remove-dynamic-nsmenuitems-from-an-nsmenu

Comment: @vadian if i do that i cant acees the menu item from outside of that function

Comment: try to remove all menu items before adding new items.

Comment: @AmirKhan i tried that and same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `NSMenu` **inside** the method

```
func applicationDockMenu(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu? {

    let dockMenu = NSMenu()
    dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "test1", action: nil, keyEquivalent:     "")
    return dockMenu
}
```

or remove the items

```
let dockMenu = NSMenu()

func applicationDockMenu(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu? {

    dockMenu.removeAllItems()
    dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "test1", action: nil, keyEquivalent:     "")
    return dockMenu
}
```

However I would declare it in Interface Builder and use an outlet.

Comment: if i put the let var in that function then i cant acess the menu items from outside of it

Comment: @AmirKhan `let` is correct as `NSMenu` is reference type